# Save view with variable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've designed a complex view in sql server 2008 R2. Which is similar as follows-

```
SELECT column1,column1 FROM Table WHERE column3=@VarName
```

I would like to save it. But I'm getting following message-

> Must declare the scalar variable "@VarName".

Any help?

Comment: Convert it to Table-Valued Function

Comment: Views are defined as a single SELECT statement, you can't have variables in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are database object that acts close to a table except to not storing data in itself, like a table.

By itself, views are restricting of using some elements like `ORDER BY` clause, parameters and so on...

If you want to deal with variables or parameters that you pass from main code, then you use `user defined functions (UDFs)`.

Table-valued functions (TVF) are similar to views and can use them in main code in `JOIN clause` and also can accept parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function instead of a view.

```
create function fntest(@varname varchar(max))
returns table as
Return (
SELECT column1,column1 FROM Table WHERE column3=@VarName
)
```